# How to convert time_usec into date format on Google BigQuery?

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery

I've the below column,

[image]

and I'd like to get the date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format from the `time_usec` column.

[image]

Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below

```
select time_usec, date(timestamp_micros(time_usec)) date
from your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be the following:

```
SELECT 
   TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP "1970-01-01 00:00:00+00",
      INTERVAL 1635500264544000 MICROSECOND) AS t1;
```

Here we use the `TIMESTAMP_ADD` function to add the microseconds value to the base epoch.